# COUNT(INVOICE.INV_NUM) giving different answers in two separate scenarios

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have written a query where I want to display the "Customer Number" (CUSTOMER table), the "Number of Invoices" (INVOICE table), which is the total invoices for each customer, and the "Total Cus Purchases" (calculated by joining the CUSTOMER, INVOICE, and LINE tables), which is the total of all the purchases in all of the invoices belonging to each customer.

The first query spits out the wrong "Number of Invoices".

```
--First Query    
SELECT CUSTOMER.CUST_NUM AS "Customer Number",
COUNT(INVOICE.INV_NUM) AS "Number of Invoices",
SUM(LINE.LINE_UNITS * LINE.LINE_PRICE) AS "Total Cus Purchases"
FROM CUSTOMER
JOIN INVOICE
ON CUSTOMER.CUST_NUM = INVOICE.CUST_NUM
JOIN LINE
ON INVOICE.INV_NUM = LINE.INV_NUMBER
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.CUST_NUM;

Customer Code Number of Invoices Total Cus Purchases
```

---

```
     1000              5              188.72
     1003              6               432.8
     1001              3               34.92
     1002              1               70.44
```

However, the second query (this is noticed when omitting the join statement for LINE, which is used to calculate the "Total Cus Purchases") spits out the correct "Number of Invoices".

```
--Second Query
SELECT 
CUSTOMER.CUST_NUM AS "Customer Number", 
COUNT(INVOICE.INV_NUM) AS "Number of Invoices"
FROM INVOICE
JOIN CUSTOMER ON INVOICE.CUST_NUM = CUSTOMER.CUST_NUM
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.CUST_NUM;

Customer Code Number of Invoices

     1000                  3
     1003                  2
     1001                  2
     1002                  1
```

How do I correct the First Query so that it spits out the values shown in the Second Query?

(Note: The total cus purchases is correct, its just the "Number of Invoices" column that is wrong.)

Comment: If one of these answers solved your problem you should accept it so that other users can find the solution and the question can be closed. If they didn't please provide more information so that the question can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT(DISTINCT)` solves the counting problem, but you can also simplify the query by removing the `JOIN` to the `CUSTOMER` table:

```
SELECT i.CUST_NUM AS "Customer Number",
       COUNT(DISTINCT i.INV_NUM) AS "Number of Invoices",
       SUM(l.LINE_UNITS * l.LINE_PRICE) AS "Total Cus Purchases"
FROM INVOICE i JOIN
     LINE l
     ON i.INV_NUM = l.INV_NUMBER
GROUP BY i.CUST_NUM;
```

You are using `CUST_NUM` and it is in the `INVOICE` table.

Comment: It's just barely possible that this is an MCVE :) and OP actually wants some fields from the customer table...